Chinese Language: Getting out of Beta..?
According to Area 51 we don't have much hope of getting out of beta on two big fronts:
3.8 questions per day

Needs Work – 15 questions per day on average is a healthy beta, 5 questions or fewer per day needs some work. A healthy site generates lots of good content to make sure users keep coming back.

870 visits/day

Okay – 1,500 visits per day is good, 500 visits per day needs some work. A great site benefits people outside the community. Eventually, 90% of a site's traffic should come from search engines.

I've only been around here for about 3 months and it seems like things are slowing down rather than speeding up - others have mentioned before that 'bad' questions are getting lots of unnecessary up-votes as well.
How can we turn things around?
Can we ever get out of beta?

Over the past year, those figures have roughly doubled. Assuming this same rate of geometric growth, we'll only need to wait 2 more years to get out of beta.
IMHO there is one way we could help hit those numbers, and this has to do with the demographics of this site: ask more questions, especially those to do with the nuances of usage that a native speaker would know well.
Questions drive answers which together drives traffic.
Compared to other stack exchange sites, I feel that this one sees more traffic from native Chinese speakers and less from people familiar with the Q&A format. This means that you'll get a lot of crap answers, but if they're of a certain kind suited for native speakers - slang, regional differences, which synonym to use when - you'll get better answers.
We could also get better numbers via policy changes; personally I feel we should allow cursive character recognition questions, even though they are not useful for future visitors.
Finally, whilst it's nice to hit those numbers, launching a full site is up to discretion, good numbers alone are not enough. Therefore, we should avoid encouraging rubbish questions and answers just for the sake of numbers.

At this moment, the number of questions per day appears the only thing that Chinese Language SE needs to increase for graduation. Incidentally, the users on this site are not very generous with upvotes on questions ... It's hard to find questions with more than 5 upvotes.
